# Could not find live medium Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, live-usb

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my Acer V5-552G-X412 64 bit computer, and am having some trouble with it. I was able to install Windows 7 on it previously after uninstalling Windows 8, but I am now interested in getting a separate partition with Ubuntu installed. My problem is that when I try to load up Ubuntu with a USB, I used Universal USB Installer 1.9.4.8 which was linked to on the info page on the Ubuntu website.

When I restart my computer with the USB plugged in, I get to a Ubuntu loading screen, which then asks me to select a language. I do so, and then it gives a list of options like trying Ubuntu without installing, or installing it. If I pick install Ubuntu, I get into a loading screen that loads for about 60 seconds and then says "Could not find a live medium" or something like that. I did select "format USB to fat32" when installing the Ubuntu ISO on my USB. Has anyone encountered such problems before, and if so, do they have a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using a USB3 slot (usually colored blue) for the USB drive? I've had a few computers refuse to properly install from that. If so, try using a USB2 slot  (usually black).

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is the black coloured USB slot, and I've tried doing it with other USB slots to no results.